# Covariant constant field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and $\chi(M)$ be the set of smooth vector fields on a complete Riemannian manifold $M$. If the covariant derivative of $grad(f)$ is zero, i.e.,
$$\nabla_X(grad(f))=0\ \forall X\in \chi(M),$$
then can we conclude that $\Delta|grad(f)|^2$ is constant? Please give any suggestion.

Comment: What have you tried? Forgetting about the fact that the vector field is a gradient, what can you conclude about $|Y|^2$ from the fact $\nabla Y = 0?$

Comment: I think then $|Y|^2$ is constant.

Comment: You can actually show $\nabla |Y|^2 = 0$.